# 301 redirect for .ca domain to .com domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to do a .ca to .com domain 301 redirect however no matter what I do it doesn't work. I've not actually done this before so I've serached about it but the code I have in doesn't work? As my .ca domain just goes to a "not found" page. Shouldn't be be redirecting to my .com domain

Here is the code I have in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.ca [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.ca [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

I have a bunch of rules form W3TC and this snippet which I'm assuming has to do with a landing page plugin we have on the site:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lp-variation-id
RewriteRule ^go/([^/]*)/([0-9]+)/ /go/$1?lp-variation-id=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lp-variation-id
RewriteRule ^go/([^/]*)? /wp-content/plugins/landing-pages/modules/module.redirect-ab-testing.php?permalink_name=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^landing-page=([^/]*)? /wp-content/plugins/landing-pages/modules/module.redirect-ab-testing.php?permalink_name=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Advice is great! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any other rules in your htaccess file?

Comment: I've updated the bottom of the question to answer you Jon.